# How to pass by reference a button's or other control's text

Tags: .net, c++-cli, controls, pass-by-reference

```
String ^% text = button->Text ; 
text = "something" ;
```

Should change button's text, but it doesn't.

Comment: [Why strings are immutable and what are the implications of it?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406046/Why-strings-are-immutable-and-what-are-the-implica)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot work, the code only updates the object.  It doesn't reach further than that and also updates the TextBox::Text property.  It is not just because this is a string, as hinted in the duplicate link, it won't work for simple value type properties either.

This is because properties are not values, you can't create a reference to them.  They look like values from the syntax when you use them.  But certainly not when you declare them, note how you have to write a get and a set method.  So to update the displayed text in the TextBox you have to call the set method of the property.  Which isn't just a simple variable assignment, it is a method call.  Intuitively obvious perhaps, note how assigning the Text property has a lot of side effects.  You can see it on the screen.

To call a method indirectly you need another vehicle, you need a *delegate*.  Pretty similar to a function pointer in C.  Any introductory book about .NET programming will explain them.  You can declare your own delegate type, but prefer the generic ones built-in the .NET framework.  Add a reference to System.Core so you can use the generic Action<> delegate type.  You'll need to first write a method that assigns the Text property:

```
private: 
    void updateTextBox(String^ text) {
        textBox1->Text = text;
    }
```

Which would be updated with a sample method like this:

```
    void Test(Action<String^>^ updater) {
        updater("foo");
    }
```

And note how this method could update *any* text box, the delegate object you passed decides which.  You create the delegate variable with code like this:

```
    Test(gcnew Action<String^>(this, &Form1::updateTextBox));
```

Comment: Okay, I get it. Thank you very much !